# Can't sign into Flickr on iOS 7

Tags: ios, flickr, yahoo

My Flickr account credentials do not work in the Settings app on my iPad mini retina with iOS 7. Every time I enter my Yahoo username and password I get the following message:

```
 "Could not communicate with the server."
```

I have enabled two-factor authentication on this account.

I attempted to use my password, temporary access code, and even generated an application-specific password in my Yahoo account. All methods fail to sign in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had exactly the same problem and tried contacting support. Finally the only thing that let me login was turning off two-step authentication completely.

Comment: Do you have to keep it off to stay signed in?

Comment: I disabled two factor, signed in on my iPad, and re-enabled it. So far it looks ok and has remained connected, but only time will tell.